# How to debug startup Errors on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am getting this error when my App Service starts on Azure:

> An error occurred while starting the application.

I have not been able to find any relevant errors in the event logs.

How can I debug this?

Comment: The question wasn't answered. Let me rephrase: is it possible to remotely debug an azure service so that startup code can be debugged. You can't attach to the remote service unless the service is running and when it is running it is too late to debug startup code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2) page very helpful:

In particular, there is a tool in Azure called Kudu Services (Under Development Tools/Advanced Tools) which lets you open a command prompt for your site, and then run `dotnet your.dll`

This will show you the exact error message that is occurring as if you were running it on your own localhost with all output.

Steps:

1. Open Kudo
2. Go to `DEBUG CONSOLE` (Top Menu), then `CMD`
3. This will open a black command window.
4. `CD site`
5. `CD wwwroot`
6. `DIR` to list contents.  Find your dll in the list to ensure you are in the right location.
7. `DOTNET your.dll`

The site will then start up, or fail to start.  If it fails, it will show the relevant messages so you can debug.

Comment: Note that the above technique can now be run using the new "App Service Editor" instead of Kudu. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx

Comment: @GeekyMonkey, I looked at the above. I see a way to edit/view file, but not a way to actually run the app and then see the command window in order to see the output.

Comment: This was a Lifesaver!  Extremely useful for finding an exception at startup that wasn't showing up in any of the logs.